# Questions involving seperable states

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

I'm reading Mark Wilde's book Quantum Information Theory, and I'm stuck on two parts. I'm unable to prove:

1. The state $\sum_{z} p_{Z}(z) \; \rho_z \; \otimes \sigma_z $, where $\rho_z$ and $\sigma_z$ are density operators, can be written as a convex combination of pure product states - that is, it is a seperable state; and
2. Show that a convex combination of sepeable states is serperable.

I have been stuck at this point for a good hour, and I'm not sure how to proceed. Please let me know how to solve these questions.

Comment: For both (1) and (2), remember that a convex combination of convex combinations of objects from a set $A$  is still a convex combination of objects from set $A$. I'm adding the homework tag, not because I think it's actually your homework, but its difficulty level is that of homework.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post. I'm not sure how to proceed thought. In 2, for example, the convex sum adds 2 tensor products of pure product states - how is that still a convex combination of pure product states; aren't sums of tensor product states not generally tensor product states? Shankar makes a remark along this line in his book.

I'm not sure how to manipulate the expressions to get the result. Any helping in setting up the expression and manipulating them would be appreciated!

Comment: If you don't see how my hint solves (2), you probably have one of the definitions wrong. A separable state is of the form $\rho = \sum p_i \big(|\lambda_i\rangle\langle \lambda_i| \otimes |\sigma_i\rangle\langle \sigma_i|\big)$. And a sum of sums of tensor products is still a sum of a tensor products.